# extending sharepoint 2010 trial

Tags: 2010, licensing

I have been trialing Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise. when I tried to visit the trial site, it came up and said The trial period for this product has expired.

I checked the solutions and workarounds, but none of them worked.

We are not ready to buy the license yet. Is there any way to extend the trial period? I tried to use other trial license keys, but no luck. What is the best way to get this around?

Do I need to reinstall the trial(I hope not) if so, will backing up existing sites and restoring them help me to retain my existing prototypes?

your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/25/extend-sharepoint-trial-period/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't extend the trial and therefore you need to re-install everything if you plan to continue using trial.

You can only change the Key if you are upgrading from standard to enterprise.

Read more: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263204.aspx

Comment: So should I take backup and reinstall it?

Comment: The trial license is meant for testing, and evaluation of the product. Therefore, if you want to continue using trial even beyond 180 days, it's time to take backups and re-install everything:)

Comment: :) I was gonna do presentation in 3 days and convince my management team:) you r right..